# how to get data for a chart from mysql database in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jfreechart

hi want to create a chart using mysql database,so i used jfreechart and i tried this,

```
void getData() {

        try {
          String query="SELECT month,profit FROM profit";
         JDBCCategoryDataset dataset=new JDBCCategoryDataset(Database.getConnection(), query);
        JFreeChart chart =ChartFactory.createLineChart("Test", "Month", "Profit", dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,false,true,true);
        BarRenderer renderer=new BarRenderer();
        CategoryPlot plot=null;
        ChartPanel panel=new ChartPanel(chart);
        p_line.removeAll();
        p_line.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but there was a exception,

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/util/PublicCloneable
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to download `jcommon-<version>.jar` and add it to your classpath. Because this jar containing the class `org/jfree/util/PublicCloneable`